# Automator Perl Shell Script stdin

Tags: perl, shell, stdin, automator

I am creating an Automator app that, among other things, executes a shell script with the Perl shell. The code is as follows:

```
$command = ' openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out "'. $dirname .'/PushKey.pem" -in "' . $privateKeyInput . '" ';
print $command . "\n";
os.system($command);
```

This command is supposed to prompt the user to enter an import password, and to enter and verify a PEM pass phrase. When running this python command from an Automator action, however, there is never a prompt for user input. I do ask for Finder items beforehand, which are passed to the shell script action as arguments, but how can I have the user enter stuff for these inputs?

Comment: just a guess, but maybe worth posting:
maybe try exec (replace shell) rather forking... in case stdin gets closed in the latter

Comment: I finally found the solution. I just added "-passin pass:[password1] -passout pass:[password2]", and it works.